# How to reference typescript's enum value from knockout data-bind?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, enums

I'm trying to make this work (page complains about CustomerExperience being undefined):

```
<div data-bind="visible: $data.customerExperienceObservable() === CustomerExperience.Loading">
    Loading...
</div>
```

where CustomerExperience is defined in TypeScript:

```
export enum CustomerExperience {
    Loading = 1,
    Unconfigured = 2,
    Data = 3
}
```

transpiled to:

```
(function (CustomerExperience) {
    CustomerExperience[CustomerExperience["Loading"] = 1] = "Loading";
    CustomerExperience[CustomerExperience["Unconfigured"] = 2] = "Unconfigured";
    CustomerExperience[CustomerExperience["Data"] = 3] = "Data";
})(exports.CustomerExperience || (exports.CustomerExperience = {}));
var CustomerExperience = exports.CustomerExperience;
```

with context applied to an instance of one class:

```
ko.applyBindings(dataProvider);
```

I understand that I can make it work if I define CustomerExperience as a property of bound dataProvider. But I'm trying to understand whether how to do it with TypeScript enum.

Any ideas? :)

PS: For now I used === 1 to make it work.

Comment: Have you considered moving the logic into a computed observable? That way you can keep your nice, readable enums without having dependencies on the integer values in your markup.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, can you please elaborate a little more about your solution?

I defined variable as this:
public customerExperienceObservable: KnockoutObservable<CustomerExperience> = ko.observable<CustomerExperience>(CustomerExperience.Loading);

Comment: Move `$data.customerExperienceObservable() === CustomerExperience.Loading` into a KnockoutComputed variable within your knockout model. Then in the binding use it like so `visible: $data.isLoaded`

Comment: It worked! Thank you @CarrieKendall!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with this solution (thank you Carrie Kendall!):

```
public customerExperienceLoading: KnockoutComputed<boolean> = ko.computed({
    owner: this,
    read:  () => {
        return this.customerExperienceObservable() === CustomerExperience.Loading; } });
```

And bound it as regular boolean:

```
data-bind="visible: $data.customerExperienceLoading() === true"
```